# About Screenshot on webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable my webpage when user is **screenshot** or record, I want to my webpage to overlay look like Netflix

Do you have any solution for me, html + javascript or another language. Now I can not use any way to reslove.

Comment: The discussion in the duplicate suggests that Netflix only manages to do this for its actual video content, because that is delivered via Widevine - but not in general for a "whole website".